# How do you set up new class templates in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, code-templates

I mainly program Android, and one of the things I (and the rest of android programmers I'm sure) use with tenacity is `android.util.Log`. Every class I create has a

```
private static final String TAG = "ClassName";
```

tag that I write up as soon as I create the class, before I work on anything else. So, since I always create the tag I figured it would just save me on time (albeit a small amount) to just have it as part of the template for an empty class. My problem is, I don't know how or where to create code templates. Can anyone inform me on how to manage and create them?

Comment: What you're referring to are called "code templates" in Eclipse, not "stubs".

Comment: @Skaffman, thank you sir. Was gonna update, but you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @Skaffman, actually, thanks to your clarification, I found out where I need to look. Thanks again. Post an answer, credits yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to are called "code templates" in Eclipse.

Go to Eclipse Preferences, search for "templates", you'll find them under Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates.